# Subwoofer not working on subwoofer output from motherboard audio

Tags: audio, speakers

I've got an Asus Sabertooth X79 motherboard that has the usual 6 I/Os for audio. I've connected my left-right speakers to the green jack, and I have recently added a subwoofer (Polk DSW Micro Pro 3000) by connecting it to the Center/Sub (orange) jack on the back. Both speakers use a RCA to 3.5mm adapter. The left-right speakers work fine, but when the subwoofer is connected to the orange jack I get no audio coming out of the subwoofer. The only way to get audio is to use a Y-splitter on the green jack. But I am confounded as to why the orange jack won't work as I thought outputting sound for a sub was its intended purpose.

My audio dashboard shows that there is a device plugged into the green and the orange jack. Does anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly did you plug into the orange jack for the subwoofer?

Comment: 3.5mm into the orange jack, which splits into RCA for the subwoofer. I thought I made that clear. Perhaps I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No, you are not clear at all.  There are many types of *"3.5mm"* plugs.

Comment: I would disagree given the context, but whatever.